# Solve two equations of Linear Inequality involving three different variables through code

Tags: c++, algorithm, linear-programming

I have two linear inequality equations with me, I am trying to understand how can I solve them using the code.

```
2x + z <= A
3y + z <= B
```

I know the values of `A` and `B`. I am trying to find all the possible positive values of `x` , `y` and `z` that will satisfy the given equation.

I want to solve the above equation using code but I haven't been able to come up with anything.

Any pointers are helpful. Thanks.

Comment: you have three unknowns and two equations ...

Comment: Do you understand how to solve them by hand? Perhaps with a matrix and then by simplifying the matrix? At what point did you have trouble converting what you did with pen and paper into code?

Comment: @jwezorek is my equation wrong, do you think it's possible to solve for three unknowns and two equations ?

Comment: @scohe001 no I haven't solved it by hand yet, let me think

Comment: [Anything that would implement rref on a matrix](https://i.imgur.com/o2ESg4g.png) can give you readily usable answers to these questions, and they're not too difficult to code yourself if you don't have anything programmatic available for that

Comment: @zenwraight That's a math problem rather than a programming one. The solution set is a region in the first octant bound by two planes. It's not clear what you mean by "*all the possible positive values*" since there can be infinitely many points in that region.

Answer (score 3):

Linear inequalities can be represented as boolean expressions. Either the inequality is true, or false. We can use a function in C++ just like a function in mathematics here.

```
bool equation_one(double x, double z, double A)
{
   return ((2 * x) + z <= A);
}

bool equation_two(double y, double z, double A)
{
   return ((3 * y) + z <= A);
}
```

Then, if we wanted to see if any values satisfies these equations, we can just try values.

NOTE: This is horribly inefficient. We are looking at cubic time bounds. But, this is much more straight forward then using a linear algebra technique.

```
for(double x = 0; x <= A/2; x++)
   for(double y = 0; y <= B/3; y++)
     for(double z = 0; z <= A && z <= B; z++)
        if(equation_one(x, z, A) && equation_two(y, z, B))
           //These are the values we want!
```

EDIT: My bad, you said positive values only. Fixed.

EDIT 2: Thought I'd provide some output. For A = 20 and B = 20, these are all possible positive integer values that satisfy the equations with x, y, and z respectively.

```
0 0 0
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 0 3
0 0 4
0 0 5
0 0 6
0 0 7
0 0 8
0 0 9
0 0 10
0 0 11
0 0 12
0 0 13
0 0 14
0 0 15
0 0 16
0 0 17
0 0 18
0 0 19
0 0 20
0 1 0
0 1 1
0 1 2
0 1 3
0 1 4
0 1 5
0 1 6
0 1 7
0 1 8
0 1 9
0 1 10
0 1 11
0 1 12
0 1 13
0 1 14
0 1 15
0 1 16
0 1 17
0 2 0
0 2 1
0 2 2
0 2 3
0 2 4
0 2 5
0 2 6
0 2 7
0 2 8
0 2 9
0 2 10
0 2 11
0 2 12
0 2 13
0 2 14
0 3 0
0 3 1
0 3 2
0 3 3
0 3 4
0 3 5
0 3 6
0 3 7
0 3 8
0 3 9
0 3 10
0 3 11
0 4 0
0 4 1
0 4 2
0 4 3
0 4 4
0 4 5
0 4 6
0 4 7
0 4 8
0 5 0
0 5 1
0 5 2
0 5 3
0 5 4
0 5 5
0 6 0
0 6 1
0 6 2
1 0 0
1 0 1
1 0 2
1 0 3
1 0 4
1 0 5
1 0 6
1 0 7
1 0 8
1 0 9
1 0 10
1 0 11
1 0 12
1 0 13
1 0 14
1 0 15
1 0 16
1 0 17
1 0 18
1 1 0
1 1 1
1 1 2
1 1 3
1 1 4
1 1 5
1 1 6
1 1 7
1 1 8
1 1 9
1 1 10
1 1 11
1 1 12
1 1 13
1 1 14
1 1 15
1 1 16
1 1 17
1 2 0
1 2 1
1 2 2
1 2 3
1 2 4
1 2 5
1 2 6
1 2 7
1 2 8
1 2 9
1 2 10
1 2 11
1 2 12
1 2 13
1 2 14
1 3 0
1 3 1
1 3 2
1 3 3
1 3 4
1 3 5
1 3 6
1 3 7
1 3 8
1 3 9
1 3 10
1 3 11
1 4 0
1 4 1
1 4 2
1 4 3
1 4 4
1 4 5
1 4 6
1 4 7
1 4 8
1 5 0
1 5 1
1 5 2
1 5 3
1 5 4
1 5 5
1 6 0
1 6 1
1 6 2
2 0 0
2 0 1
2 0 2
2 0 3
2 0 4
2 0 5
2 0 6
2 0 7
2 0 8
2 0 9
2 0 10
2 0 11
2 0 12
2 0 13
2 0 14
2 0 15
2 0 16
2 1 0
2 1 1
2 1 2
2 1 3
2 1 4
2 1 5
2 1 6
2 1 7
2 1 8
2 1 9
2 1 10
2 1 11
2 1 12
2 1 13
2 1 14
2 1 15
2 1 16
2 2 0
2 2 1
2 2 2
2 2 3
2 2 4
2 2 5
2 2 6
2 2 7
2 2 8
2 2 9
2 2 10
2 2 11
2 2 12
2 2 13
2 2 14
2 3 0
2 3 1
2 3 2
2 3 3
2 3 4
2 3 5
2 3 6
2 3 7
2 3 8
2 3 9
2 3 10
2 3 11
2 4 0
2 4 1
2 4 2
2 4 3
2 4 4
2 4 5
2 4 6
2 4 7
2 4 8
2 5 0
2 5 1
2 5 2
2 5 3
2 5 4
2 5 5
2 6 0
2 6 1
2 6 2
3 0 0
3 0 1
3 0 2
3 0 3
3 0 4
3 0 5
3 0 6
3 0 7
3 0 8
3 0 9
3 0 10
3 0 11
3 0 12
3 0 13
3 0 14
3 1 0
3 1 1
3 1 2
3 1 3
3 1 4
3 1 5
3 1 6
3 1 7
3 1 8
3 1 9
3 1 10
3 1 11
3 1 12
3 1 13
3 1 14
3 2 0
3 2 1
3 2 2
3 2 3
3 2 4
3 2 5
3 2 6
3 2 7
3 2 8
3 2 9
3 2 10
3 2 11
3 2 12
3 2 13
3 2 14
3 3 0
3 3 1
3 3 2
3 3 3
3 3 4
3 3 5
3 3 6
3 3 7
3 3 8
3 3 9
3 3 10
3 3 11
3 4 0
3 4 1
3 4 2
3 4 3
3 4 4
3 4 5
3 4 6
3 4 7
3 4 8
3 5 0
3 5 1
3 5 2
3 5 3
3 5 4
3 5 5
3 6 0
3 6 1
3 6 2
4 0 0
4 0 1
4 0 2
4 0 3
4 0 4
4 0 5
4 0 6
4 0 7
4 0 8
4 0 9
4 0 10
4 0 11
4 0 12
4 1 0
4 1 1
4 1 2
4 1 3
4 1 4
4 1 5
4 1 6
4 1 7
4 1 8
4 1 9
4 1 10
4 1 11
4 1 12
4 2 0
4 2 1
4 2 2
4 2 3
4 2 4
4 2 5
4 2 6
4 2 7
4 2 8
4 2 9
4 2 10
4 2 11
4 2 12
4 3 0
4 3 1
4 3 2
4 3 3
4 3 4
4 3 5
4 3 6
4 3 7
4 3 8
4 3 9
4 3 10
4 3 11
4 4 0
4 4 1
4 4 2
4 4 3
4 4 4
4 4 5
4 4 6
4 4 7
4 4 8
4 5 0
4 5 1
4 5 2
4 5 3
4 5 4
4 5 5
4 6 0
4 6 1
4 6 2
5 0 0
5 0 1
5 0 2
5 0 3
5 0 4
5 0 5
5 0 6
5 0 7
5 0 8
5 0 9
5 0 10
5 1 0
5 1 1
5 1 2
5 1 3
5 1 4
5 1 5
5 1 6
5 1 7
5 1 8
5 1 9
5 1 10
5 2 0
5 2 1
5 2 2
5 2 3
5 2 4
5 2 5
5 2 6
5 2 7
5 2 8
5 2 9
5 2 10
5 3 0
5 3 1
5 3 2
5 3 3
5 3 4
5 3 5
5 3 6
5 3 7
5 3 8
5 3 9
5 3 10
5 4 0
5 4 1
5 4 2
5 4 3
5 4 4
5 4 5
5 4 6
5 4 7
5 4 8
5 5 0
5 5 1
5 5 2
5 5 3
5 5 4
5 5 5
5 6 0
5 6 1
5 6 2
6 0 0
6 0 1
6 0 2
6 0 3
6 0 4
6 0 5
6 0 6
6 0 7
6 0 8
6 1 0
6 1 1
6 1 2
6 1 3
6 1 4
6 1 5
6 1 6
6 1 7
6 1 8
6 2 0
6 2 1
6 2 2
6 2 3
6 2 4
6 2 5
6 2 6
6 2 7
6 2 8
6 3 0
6 3 1
6 3 2
6 3 3
6 3 4
6 3 5
6 3 6
6 3 7
6 3 8
6 4 0
6 4 1
6 4 2
6 4 3
6 4 4
6 4 5
6 4 6
6 4 7
6 4 8
6 5 0
6 5 1
6 5 2
6 5 3
6 5 4
6 5 5
6 6 0
6 6 1
6 6 2
7 0 0
7 0 1
7 0 2
7 0 3
7 0 4
7 0 5
7 0 6
7 1 0
7 1 1
7 1 2
7 1 3
7 1 4
7 1 5
7 1 6
7 2 0
7 2 1
7 2 2
7 2 3
7 2 4
7 2 5
7 2 6
7 3 0
7 3 1
7 3 2
7 3 3
7 3 4
7 3 5
7 3 6
7 4 0
7 4 1
7 4 2
7 4 3
7 4 4
7 4 5
7 4 6
7 5 0
7 5 1
7 5 2
7 5 3
7 5 4
7 5 5
7 6 0
7 6 1
7 6 2
8 0 0
8 0 1
8 0 2
8 0 3
8 0 4
8 1 0
8 1 1
8 1 2
8 1 3
8 1 4
8 2 0
8 2 1
8 2 2
8 2 3
8 2 4
8 3 0
8 3 1
8 3 2
8 3 3
8 3 4
8 4 0
8 4 1
8 4 2
8 4 3
8 4 4
8 5 0
8 5 1
8 5 2
8 5 3
8 5 4
8 6 0
8 6 1
8 6 2
9 0 0
9 0 1
9 0 2
9 1 0
9 1 1
9 1 2
9 2 0
9 2 1
9 2 2
9 3 0
9 3 1
9 3 2
9 4 0
9 4 1
9 4 2
9 5 0
9 5 1
9 5 2
9 6 0
9 6 1
9 6 2
10 0 0
10 1 0
10 2 0
10 3 0
10 4 0
10 5 0
10 6 0
```

Comment: Thanks @Lucas Streanga for your answer, so for the y value the range should be from 0 to B/3 right as second equation is 3y + z <= B .

Comment: My mistake, didn't realize A wasn't the right size of both equations. I'll fix it. Yes, the range should be B/3 since the max value of y for the equation to be true is B/3.

Comment: Thanks @Lucas Streanga do you know the matrix way as well to solve this in a faster way.

Comment: @zenwraight matrix way is possible only for system of equalities where number of equations is the same as unknowns. So in order to use matrices you need to convert your inequalities to equalities using algebraic rules. Then loop one common unknown `z` (brute force) and for each compute x,y directly by matrix ...

Comment: Got it, so it's not that straightforward, make sense.